# UICollectionView or UITableView to be more than screen size

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uicollectionview

I need to display a table of data ; rows and columns. I thought UICollectionView would resolve my problem and resorted to it, rather than going in for UITableView. UICollectionView's flowLayout (the out-of-the-box layout) does indeed display more than one column of data. But can I make it display content for more than one screen width ? Say, I want the UICollectionView to display 3 screen widths of data (for example, for iPhone, it's 320*3=960px)? By default, UICollectionView's FlowLayout seems to break data display at the screen width and proceed to display the rest in the next line. Now, I don't want it to break at the end of the page-width, but at the end of (3 * page-width).

What I tried:
I put the CollectionView inside a UIScrollView and set the scrollview's width to 3*page-width like this:

[image]

```
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].width*3.0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
```

When I run the App, the page does show the width of 3*page-width. Am able to scroll horizintally well. But still, the UICollectionView data breaks at one page-wdith and continues display un the next row (meaning it does not consider the scrollview's width as its width ; rather, it continues to consider the page-width as its width).

Kindly provide your suggestions/comments. It will be of great help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just change the scroll direction so the Flow Layout will scroll horizontally instead of vertically:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
```

You can also set this directly in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks! I started on this, but paused when I read it's going to be a lot of work creating a custom UICollectionViewLayout. So, I thought it would be better if some tweak to the UICollectionViewFlowLayout was possible to achieve the same result, rather than writing a custom layout just because am not able to tweak one single property! Have you tried writing a custom CollectionViewLayout? Is it too messy?

Comment: @Jean I updated the answer with a better solution to not use a custom layout, but rather to modify the Flow Layout.